# CMS_decrypt failed with error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

Tags: c, openssl, rtos

Hi I am trying to use CMS_decrypt()  , but it is returning 0 , which is failure . On printing openssl error it is returning 0 .

below is what have tried .

```
  in = BIO_new_file("cms_encrypted_output.txt", "r");
  if (NULL == in) {
       printf("BIO new license file failed");
   }
   cms = d2i_CMS_bio(in , NULL);
   if (NULL == cms) {
         printf("d2i_CMS_bio license file failed");
    }


 /* Decrypt S/MIME message */
  if(!CMS_decrypt(cms, rkey, rcert, NULL, out, 0)){
      printf("openssl error [%s], ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
      printf("CMS_decrypt failed");
 }
```

below is the output :
openssl error :: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
CMS_decrypt failed